# select previous element and apply effect using css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have 3 `<div>`s in one horizontal line. each width = 33.33% and I want to change width of one `div` on hover to 50% and other two to 25%.

```
<div id="A"></div>
<div id="B"></div>
<div id="C"></div>
```

I can apply this for A as

```
#A:hover{width:50%}
#A:hover+#B
{width:25%}
#A:hover~#C
{width:25%}
```

and it work fine.

when we hover B

```
#B:hover{width:50%}
#B:hover+#A
{width:25%}
#B:hover~#C
{width:25%}
```

B expand to 50% and C shrink to 25%. but #A remain 33.33%.

How can I fix this.

Comment: You would have to do this with JS because CSS stands for **Cascading**, so you can't go up the tree.

Comment: Do you want `css` only solution?

Comment: @Maverick CSS selectors can't go up the tree, but hover events (as many other events) bubble in the tree. See Vitorino answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flexbox can do that without a parent selctor:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.parent {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 1em auto;
  display: flex;
}
.child {
  height: 150px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  flex: 1;
  transition: flex 1s ease;
}
.child:hover {
  flex: 0 0 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

In `Css` there is no previous selectors

- by default the width is `33.33%`
- on hover of the parent the `width` is changed to `25%`
- on hover of the `div` inside the width is changed
  to `50%`

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.par {
  overflow: hidden; /* to clear floats */
}
.par div {
  width: 33.33%; /* default width */
  transition: .2s linear;
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 100px;
  float: left;
}
.par:hover div {
  width: 25%; /* width when you hover on parent */
}
.par div:hover {
  width: 50% /* width when you hover on the element */
}
```

```html
<div class="par">
  <div id="A">1</div>
  <div id="B">2</div>
  <div id="C">3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Good solution. The key here is that there should be no space between the elements (as there are 3 of them and each are 33.33%). If there was any space (like margin top/bottom on child, padding top/bottom on parent) between container and children then it would need JS.

Comment: yes @Harry but OP had mentioned _on hover to 50% and other two to 25%_ so he wants the total to come to `100%`

Comment: That's true but width doesn't have mean top/bottom padding/margin can't be there :) So with one of those being present, the `hover` effect would be triggered even if the user isn't actually hovering a child.

Comment: @harry in that case you could add top or bottom transparent borders on the wrapper

Comment: @FabrizioCalderan: Absolutely, there are ways to make this approach work. I only wanted to highlight to OP that there are certain factors which they would need to consider :)